# My USB Wifi is very slow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, internet

My wifi is very slow on Ubuntu 20.04. This is not a problem on Windows. To verify I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, everything was okay until I updated Ubuntu.

When I restarted my computer after installing updates,

1. My wifi was showing very weak signal in the Ubuntu UI.
2. The internet was very slow.

How do I fix this? I think it has something to do with the update I ran.

This is the output of `lsmod | grep rtl`

```
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             688128  51 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Output of `lsusb` command

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0202 SiGma Micro Usb KeyBoard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 275d:0ba6  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Should we guess what is "your wifi"? My Wi-Fi isn't slow. Why `rtl`? Is it USB or PCI?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I use USB Wifi adapter.

Comment: So what is the adapter?

Comment: Its a TP-Link adapter. Does the lsbusb command answer your question :)?

Comment: Now you can search by the adapter and find drivers for it.

Comment: Is it necessary to install drivers manually? My wifi worked flawlessly until a few weeks ago.

Comment: There may be a lot of reasons why Wi-Fi is slow, e.g. neighbors, etc. It maybe not related to the OS at all.

Comment: It is a Ubuntu related issue cause it works much better on Windows like I said in my original question.